# HOW to put PIE graphs in Power-point presentation with slide by slide

Tags: c#, graph, powerpoint

I Have more than 25 Pie graphs I want to put them in one power-point presentation with different slide .

```
public PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();
public PowerPoint.Slides objSlides;
public PowerPoint._Slide objSlide;
public PowerPoint.TextRange objTextRng;

void putinPResen(string item)
{
    WAIT_FORM wait3 = new WAIT_FORM();

    try
    {
        pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(MsoTriState.msoTrue);
        string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        objSlides = pptPresentation.Slides;
        objSlide = objSlides.Add(Count, 
            PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly);
        objTextRng = objSlide.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange;
        objTextRng.Text = item.ToString();
        objTextRng.Font.Name = "Comic Sans MS";
        objTextRng.Font.Size = 40;
        objSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(path + "\\chart" + Count + ".png",   
            MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, 150, 150, 500, 350);
        File.Delete(path + "\\chart" + Count + ".png");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        wait3.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    } 
}

SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.pptx)|*.pptx|All files (*.*)|*.*";

if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout = 
        pptPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts  
        [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];

    pptPresentation.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName, 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault, 
        MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

When i execute this program I had  got multi power-point and one catch message is  integer out of range from . 2 is not range..

can you help on this ...thanks fistly

Comment: Are you calling any of any of this in a loop? Where is the code for this loop?

Comment: i am calling this putinPResen  function in loop

Comment: I got output...what i want... put the condition for pptpresentation variable and got a desirable output but thanks for give a reply

Comment: Which line does the exception occur at? Does it happen every time or just on a particular call to the function?

Comment: Also I noticed the [Slides.Add method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff761456%28v%3doffice.14%29) is _"reserved for internal use"_ - maybe you should be using the [Slides.AddSlide method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff763789%28v%3doffice.14%29)